# Plotting Simple Expression

Tags: plotting

I want to plot

```
y = 1 - (1 + x^4 - 2 x^4)/(1 + x^4 - 2 x^2 cos (2*omega*beta*L))

x = .2;
beta = .5;
L = 2;

Plot[y[omega], {omega, 0, 3 Pi}]
```

where I vary omega. Could anyone help me. It won't display a figure.

Comment: `y[omega_]:=...`?

Comment: Fix your call to `Cos`: `y = 1 - (1 + x^4 - 2 x^4)/(1 + x^4 - 2 x^2 Cos[2*omega*beta*L])` and then `Plot[y, {omega, 0, 3 Pi}]` will work.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two options. Before we get to those, we need to fix your syntax.

In Mathematica functions start with uppercase and are called using square brackets - we need to fix your call to `Cos`.

```
y = 1 - (1 + x^4 - 2 x^4)/(1 + x^4 - 2 x^2 Cos[2*omega*beta*L])
```

Now to get to your actual question:

You could do:

```
Plot[y, {omega, 0, 3 Pi}]
```

which is replacing `omega` within `y`.

or, you could define `y` as a parameterised function, as pointed out by Kuba:

```
ClearAll[y]
y[omega_] := 1 - (1 + x^4 - 2 x^4)/(1 + x^4 - 2 x^2 Cos[2*omega*beta*L])
```

and then your initial idea should work:

```
Plot[y[omega], {omega, 0, 3 Pi}]
```

I would recommend reading at least the [Fast Intro for Math Students](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) to help you avoid syntactic problems in future.